# How to Create Different Outputs Based On State Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a quiz system where selecting different options will result in different outputs, however, the output is always rendered the same. What's the issue?

A user chooses between button 1 and 2, and then 3 and 4. He makes two choices which sets a particular state for this scenario. Eg. choosing 1 and 3 results in ['a','c']. When the output button is pressed, it will check against all the option results and console.log the output for the specific scenario.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import stylesheet from "./stylesheet.css";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { myArray: [] };
}

firstHandler = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    myArray: [...previousState.myArray, "a"]
  }));
};
 secondHandler = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    myArray: [...previousState.myArray, "b"]
  }));
 };
 thirdHandler = () => {
   this.setState(previousState => ({
   myArray: [...previousState.myArray, "c"]
   }));
  };
  fourthHandler = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    myArray: [...previousState.myArray, "d"]
  }));
  };

  output = () => {
   const ar1 = [];
    if (this.state.myArray.values === ar1.values) {
   return console.log("Death");
   } else if (this.state.myArray.values === ["a", "b"].values) {
   return console.log("Life");
   } else if (this.state.myArray.values === ["a", "d"].values) {
   return console.log("Wealth");
    } else {
  return console.log("Dispair");
     }
  };
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div className="row-one">
      <button className="option-one" onClick={this.firstHandler}>
        button 1
      </button>
      <button className="option-two" onClick={this.secondHandler}>
        button 2
      </button>
     </div>
     <div className="row-two">
       <button className="option-three" onClick={this.thirdHandler}>
         button 1
       </button>
       <button className="option-four" onClick={this.fourthHandler}>
         button 2
        </button>
       </div>
        <div>{this.state.myArray}</div>
      <button onClick={this.output}>...</button>
     </div>
     );
       }
    }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Keeps on outputting  'Death' regardless of the options chosen

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that, you think .values function from array returns a representation of array values that you can compare against other, while that's not the case. values() returns an iterator for the values of an array, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values).

You have several options for comparing array values. I would suggest a simple approach of performing a sort and then generating string representation of array values. Replace your method output with the following:

```
  output = () => {
    const ar1 = [];
    let newArra = this.state.myArray.slice().sort().toString();

    if (newArra === ar1.toString()) {
      return console.log("Death");
    } else if (newArra === ["a", "b"].toString()) {
      return console.log("Life");
    } else if (newArra === ["a", "d"].toString()) {
      return console.log("Wealth");
    } else {
      return console.log("Dispair");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the death... is that the first if statement is always true since `this.state.myArray.values and ar1.values` are undefined which result to true based on this expression `this.state.myArray.values === ar1.values` see help below :

```
output = () => {
    // const ar1 = [];
    const myArray = this.state.myArray;

    // check the lenth if 0 then 'death'
    if (!myArray.length) {
      return console.log("Death");
    } else {
      // if you want the array to have only two values uncomment below code
      // myArray.length = 2;
      if (myArray.includes("a") && myArray.includes("b")) {
        return console.log("Life");
      } else if (myArray.includes("a") && myArray.includes("d")) {
        return console.log("Wealth");
      } else {
        return console.log("Dispair");
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is wrong, mostly because the way you try to access the array values is wrong. The array comparison:

```
if (this.state.myArray.values === ar1.values) {
      return console.log("Death");
}
```

will be always be true. This is because `this.state.myArray.values` is a `Array` class function, and you are comparing it with the `Array` class function from `ar1`. Obviously, they are  the same, and that's why you always receive true on that condition. What you mean to use here is:

```
if (this.state.myArray.values() === ar1.values()) {
      return console.log("Death");
}
```

but that will not work either, because `Array.values()` returns a new array operator with the content of the array, and the identity operator `===` will return false since they are different arrays even when the contents is the same. (Even if you compare `ar1.values() === ar1.values()` will return false). In case you wonder, the equality operator `==` will not work either.

In general, array content comparison in javascript is not something easy to do. I would recommend you to use another approach, like using different `FLAGS`, or an `object`. But if you still preferring keep using array comparison, take a look to [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)